# How to communicate with fragments in TabHost Activity

Tags: android, fragmenttransaction, fragment-tab-host, navigation-drawer

I am using a Navigation Drawer Activity inside that I have let  say xyz Fragment , inside xyz fragment I have FragmentTabHost . Now I want to change Fragment in FragmentTabHost onClick on a button from a fragment in FragmentTabHost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check [this code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NavigationDrawer/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationdrawer/NavigationDrawerActivity.java)

Which is part of the official google sample for using a Navigation Drawer with Fragments project.